# Connect another database in library in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, oracle, codeigniter, postgresql

I use two databases, oracle and postgresql. Postgre database is on default and I want to connect oracle where it is needed only. So how can I do this?

Now I want to connect oracle database in my library.

My Code in Library:

```
     function find_all_subjects($id1,$id2)
{
    $DB1 = $this->load->database('database2', TRUE);
    $sql="sql here";
    $query=$DB1->query($sql);
    return  $query->result();

}
```

But its giving error below:

```
Severity: Notice

 Message: Undefined property: Somefunction::$load
```

Do anyone what's wrong with the code or how to connect another database??

Comment: I guess before V3 Codeigniter did not include the super object by default in the libraries, so you'll need to define it using &get_instance(); then you can load & do whatever you want

Comment: how to do that please elaborate....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (Not Tested):

```
class Classname {

    protected $CI;

    protected $database2;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->database2 = $this->CI->load->database('database2', TRUE);
    }

    public function function_name () {
        $this->database2->query('...');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the CodeIgniter documentation

> To access CodeIgniter's native resources within your library use the
>   get_instance() function. This function returns the CodeIgniter super
>   object.

This means in your model you need to do the following

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$DB1 = $CI->load->database('database2', TRUE);
```